# Idiomatic way to handle JPA criteria ordering in Kotlin

Tags: jpa, kotlin, criteria-api

I have a `CriteriaBuilder`-based query that can be ordered by several different properties.

Currently it's being handled somehow like this:

```
when(filters.sortBy) {
    "foo" -> query.orderBy(if(isAsc) cb.asc("bar") else cb.desc("bar"))
    "baz" -> query.orderBy(if(isAsc) cb.asc("quux") else cb.desc("quux"))
}
```

It's definitely not the most readable or maintainable code I've ever written.

Is there a better and possibly more idiomatic way to do this in Kotlin, given that it doesn't have the ternary `? :` operator?

Note that some of the properties I need to order by may be subproperties of the root object, so just extracting this to a method that takes a string as the name of the order clause may not be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when` is an expression, so you can use it's result directly as an argument in `query.orderBy()`

Also, local function would help to eliminate if-else duplication part

```
 fun query(...) {
    ...   
    fun sort(name: String) = if (isAsc) cb.asc(name) else cb.desc(name)
    query.orderBy(sort(
            when (filters.sortBy) {
                "foo" -> "bar"
                "baz" -> "quux"
            }
    ))
    ...
 }
```